# how to change color of GMS Marker and how to add Custom GMS Marker?

Tags: google-maps, colors, icons, google-maps-markers, google-maps-sdk-ios

I want to use my own marker instead of red marker (destination) shown in screenshot and also I want to change marker color from red to blue here is the code.

[image]

```
let sourceMarker = GMSMarker()
sourceMarker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
    latitude: currentLocationCoordinates!.coordinate.latitude,
    longitude: currentLocationCoordinates!.coordinate.longitude
)
sourceMarker.title = "Current Location"
sourceMarker.map = self.mapView

// MARK: Marker for destination location
let destinationMarker = GMSMarker()
destinationMarker.position = CLLocationCoordinate2D(
    latitude: selectedLocation!.latitude,
    longitude: selectedLocation!.longitude
)
destinationMarker.title = "Destination"
destinationMarker.map = self.mapView
```

Comment: I've never written any IOS code but the [documentation suggests you can Tint a marker icon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/reference/interface_g_m_s_marker#a5150f69650d08db602aa6e5a6710c4f2) to make it a different colour

Answer (score 0):

You can use icon property of Marker to customise marker images

Here is official documentation

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker#customize-the-marker-image

You can also customise marker colours

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/ios-sdk/marker#change-the-marker-color